# RESTAdapter - server response format

Tags: ember.js

I am extending the RESTAdapter and it is communicating with the backend as it should - but I do have a problem with the following error: 
Assertion Failed: You made a request for a user with id 5, but the adapter's response did not have any data.

Although I return any user I want and display the data into the console, this error keeps appearing. I guess this is because my reponses' naming format is not compatible with ember.

e.g. `{"result":[{"username":"billyjoe","id":5}],"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":15223}`

is the server's reponse.

My question: in what format should I get the response so that Ember does what it should, include the record(s) into the store and not throw an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exact request would be:

```
{  
  user: {
   "username":"billyjoe",
   "id":5
  }
}
```

If you were to request a collection of some sort

```
{  
  users: [{
   "username":"billyjoe",
   "id":5
  }]
}
```